# how to download any file to any device and view?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

The below code is an API call in which I'm passing a documentID and I'm trying to open a document. Due to the fact that this whole process is running on a server I'm not able to view the file on any other device(be it another desktop or mobile device) although the file will open up in server machine but wont open locally. Can anyone please guide me through as to where I'm going wrong ? 
(sorry for the code, I know it might not be perfect as I'm new to web dev. still learning).

```
    {
        int i = 1;
        string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhysicalDocumentPath"]; // some address like "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\folder\documents...."
        string key2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhysicalDocumentPath2"]; // "C:\{somefolder}\{somefolder}...."
        JAppDoc value = new JAppDoc();
        var response = new Response();           
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(key2))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(key2);
            }

            IAppDataService appDataService = new AppDataService();
            response = appDataService.GetDoc(docId, value);               

            var fileName = value.ApplicantId + "_" + value.DocumentName;
            var savefileName = fileName;
            var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(key, fileName);
            var prevPath = fileSavePath;
            var nextPath = fileSavePath;
            var tmp = fileName.Split('.');
            var tmp1 = tmp[0];                
            while (File.Exists(nextPath))
            {
                tmp = fileName.Split('.');                    
                fileName = tmp1 + i.ToString();
                fileName = fileName + "." + tmp[1];
                savefileName = fileName;                    
                nextPath = Path.Combine(key, savefileName);
                if (File.Exists(nextPath))
                {
                    prevPath = nextPath;
                }
                i++;
            }

            try
            {
                tmp = prevPath.Split(new[] { "Docs\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                var serverpath = key + tmp[1];
                var localpath = key2+ tmp[1];
                if (File.Exists(localpath))
                {
                    Process.Start(localpath);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(serverpath, localpath);
                    Process.Start(localpath);
                }
            }
           catch(Exception e)
            {
                Utils.Write(e);
                response.Message = "File not found !";                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.Write(ex);
        }

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

Comment: you need to send the file (or to be precise, the file's contents) back to the client in the response. You can google for lots of examples based on WebAPI, but using a `FileResult` (instead of just simply `Ok()`) is a simple way to do it.

Comment: The call is made via AngulaJS controller. Will I be able to get the FileResult Response as that file ?? can you please guide a bit more ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you making an ajax call or a full HTTP request? Downloading files via ajax does not really work because it tries to send the file content into the webpage (inside a Javascript variable) rather than sending it to the browser as a standard file download. If you're trying to do it via ajax, consider providing something like a hyperlink which will visit the download URL in a new tab instead, or trigger that same behaviour via script if need be.

Comment: I'm calling it via full HTTP request in angularjs file

Comment: In that case it should not be a problem. You can of course always test your Web API endpoint separately by requesting via the browser, or via another tool like PostMan. Then you move onto testing the client code which calls it for real.

Comment: When I try to use FileResult / FileStreamResult it says to use using System.Web.Mvc; which in turn creates error for other calls like [Route][HTTPGet] etc. Cant use both at a time ?

Comment: So sorry, I realised the FileResult I use is a custom class. I will post it up as an answer you can try to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what I have done is just returning back the full path of the file from Api to AngularJS controller and I'm using  condition

if (response.data.message != null)
                    window.open('//'+response.data.message);
 else
                    alert("File Not Found !");

in the message part the file path is there.
This opens the file in a new tab in the web browser. Thank you everyone for your support . learnt a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For downloading files from Web API I use a custom `FileResult` response which inherits from `IHttpActionResult`, as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Http Action Result containing the requested document
/// </summary>
public class FileResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly string filePath;
    private readonly string contentType;
    private readonly byte[] content;
    private readonly string fileName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialise the action result with the path to the file and the content type. The contents of the file will be read.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FilePath">Path to the file to read</param>
    /// <param name="ContentType">Type of content</param>
    public FileResult(string FilePath, string ContentType = null)
    {
        filePath = FilePath;
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
        contentType = ContentType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialise the action result with the contents of the file, it's filename and the content type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Content"></param>
    /// <param name="FileName"></param>
    /// <param name="ContentType"></param>
    public FileResult(byte[] Content, string FileName, string ContentType)
    {
        content = Content;
        fileName = FileName;
        contentType = ContentType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The token to monitor for cancellation requests.</param>
    /// <returns>A task that, when completed, contains the System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.</returns>
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            HttpContent output;
            if (filePath != null)
            {
                output = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filePath));
            }
            else
            {
                output = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(content));
            }

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = output
            };

            var mappedContentType = contentType ?? MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetExtension(filePath));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mappedContentType);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;

            return response;
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You can pass in a file path or a stream of bytes depending on what you need.

For your particular case you can probably replace `Process.Start(localpath);` with something like:

```
return new FileResult(localpath, fileName, "application/octet-stream");
```

As a consequence you also don't need `return Ok(response);`. I can't see your action method's signature but it should return an `IHttpActionResult` or you could specify `FileResult` directly as the return type if you prefer.

(Of course if you have more accurate MIME Type information for your files you should use that instead of "application/octet-stream".)

Comment: I'm very sorry but I checked it right now and it seems like I'm making an ajax call using angularJS.

Method.postObj("applicant/document", docdetails).then(function (response) {
                $("#uploadDialog").ejDialog("close");
                Method.getbyId("applicant/document/app

Comment: this.post = function (path, param) {
            var request = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: appSetting.apiBaseUrl + path + "/",
                dataType: 'json.....................

Comment: Well that's nothing to do with the Web API / C# solution, which is what you asked for, and which works ok if you use a regular HTTP request. I suggested you an alternative approach to take in the comments on the main question. Meanwhile you can test the API part separately to ensure it works as expected before implementing the JS.

Comment: Ok so can you guide how to I convert the files to HTML on server so that user might be able to view that file under any condition ? For now there is no restriction on the type of file a user can view. It can be anything like text,image etc. Or just how to download the file so that user can just open it as per their choice ?

Comment: not sure what you mean by convert to HTML? You mean embed inside a web page? Not everything can be embedded in a web page, mainly just images TBH. Right now the code above will already allow the user to download the file and view it however they like. They just need to make a  valid HTTP request to that action method

Comment: can you tell me how to use this file result ? where should i put this code to download the file?

Comment: wherever you like. The point is it must cause the user to visit the URL of the action method which returns the FileResult. It could be a hyperlink they click on, you you could make some Javascript which does `window.open()` or `window.location` to point to that URL, it's up to you. Like I said already, it just needs to be a valid HTTP request to the action (but not via ajax)